# How do I make the PHP CLI use newlines on OS X?

Tags: php, macos, terminal, newline, command-line-interface

I have a problem with PHP's interactive shell on the Mac OS X terminal. Namely, it doesn't have line breaks after each command:

```
php > echo "Hello Stack Overflow!";
Hello echo "As you can see, there was no newline.";                            As you can see, there was no newline.php > echo "As you can see, there was no newlineecho "It even deletes my sentences if I go up and then down in history."; 
It even deletes my sentences if I go up and then down in history.php >
```

As you can tell, I can't even go up and down in my history, because it corrupts the buffer and makes it so I do not know what I am typing. Does anyone know how to fix this?

My PHP version:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.24 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2014 21:32:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ php > echo "Hello" . PHP_EOL . "World!";
```

The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform. Available since PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.2

Comment: And I could just press Enter after every command in the CLI. I'm not going to type 8-10 more characters just for a line break on every command. And where's your `-a`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want new lines in CLI, use the explicit return carriage:

```
$ php > echo "Hello\r\nWorld!";
```

should output:

```
$ Hello
World!
```

Comment: `\r\n` is the line ending for Windows... also, why do you have `$ php` without the -a switch?